# Is there any way to get current intl value outside a react component

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

can we get current intl(locale) value outside react component?

```
const locales = {
  locale: 'en',
  messages: {},
};

import { IntlProvider, addLocaleData } from 'react-intl';

//below is for creating 
const intlProvider = new IntlProvider(locales, {});
const { intl } = intlProvider.getChildContext();

//is there any code snippet to get current value from IntlProvider?
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `createIntl` API: https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/api/#createintl

Comment: Above code is for creating. I need some snippet which can current intl value in JavaScript helper files

Comment: I'm saying you should not get the `intl` object from `intlProvider.getChildContext()` since that no longer works in later react-intl version. You should use `createIntl` instead and pass it down